# Are all spin states orthogonal?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-spin

For a spin 1/2 particle you have two spin states, either up or down which are orthogonal. But what about a spin 1 particle which has 3 spin states, either up, down, not up/not down?

Comment: The orthogonality of the spin states does not mean that there directions in space is perpendicular !! The meaning of orthogonality has to do with the idea that spin up and spin down states entirely independent states (in the case of spin-half). With spin-1 there are three such independent states. Spin of the particle has nothing to do with space dimensions.

Answer (score 9):

It is a common misconception that a spin-½ particle can only be in spin "up" or "down" states. For one, it is well known that such a quantum particle can also be in a superposition of such states. Additionally, the up and down states are related to a given spatial direction, but the particles are spherically symmetric, so what about the other directions?

It turns out that both those concerns are the same. If a particle has spin states $|\!\uparrow\rangle$, "up", and $|\!\downarrow\rangle$, "down", which represent positive and negative projections of the angular momentum along the $z$ axis, then there are also "right" and "left" states,
$$
|\!\rightarrow\rangle=\frac{|\!\uparrow\rangle+|\!\downarrow\rangle}{\sqrt{2}}
\text{ and }
|\!\leftarrow\rangle=\frac{|\!\uparrow\rangle-|\!\downarrow\rangle}{\sqrt{2}},
$$
which have positive and negative projections of the angular momentum along the $x$ axis. The most general state a spin-½ particle can have can be written in the form
$$|\psi\rangle=\cos\frac\theta2|\uparrow\rangle+e^{i\phi}\sin\frac\theta2|\!\downarrow\rangle,$$
where $\theta\in[0,\pi]$ and $\phi\in[0,2\pi)$ are the spherical coordinates of the unit vector of the direction in which $|\psi\rangle$ has a definite angular momentum projection.

These states are **not** all orthogonal. In fact, for every state $|\psi\rangle$ there exists a single other state $|\bar\psi\rangle$ which is orthogonal to it (and whose unit vector, of course, points in the antipodal direction).

---

A similar thing happens with a spin-1 particle. If you fix a spatial direction as your $z$ axis, you will have a state $|\!\uparrow\rangle$ which has positive $L_z$, a state $|\!\downarrow\rangle$ which has $L_z<0$, plus a third state $|-\rangle$ with $L_z=0$. These three states are all orthogonal to each other. However, there are a multitude of other states, which can be written in general as
$$
|\psi\rangle=\alpha|\!\uparrow\rangle+\beta|-\rangle+\gamma|\!\downarrow\rangle,
$$
where $\alpha,\beta$ and $\gamma$ are complex numbers, unique up to a global phase, such that $|\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2+|\gamma|^2=1$. In general, two given states $|\psi\rangle$ and $|\psi'\rangle$ will **not** be orthogonal. Given a state $|\psi\rangle$, you can choose a maximum of **two** other states which are orthogonal to $|\psi\rangle$ and to each other. (Additionally, linear combinations of those two states will also be orthogonal to $|\psi\rangle$.)

---

The overall reason for these facts is that the state space of a particle of spin $s$ is a (complex) vector space of dimension $d=2s+1$. In such a vector space, one can only ever find up to $d$ vectors which are orthogonal to each other; two general vectors are, of course, not orthogonal.